# migrating civi database from current hosting to civihosting.com

Tags: wordpress, import, mysql, export

We recently signed up for shared hosting at civihosting.com and want to move our current site there. Both sites are running CiviCRM 4.7.29 and WordPress 4.9.1.

I cannot get into the CiviCRM dashboard on the current site (the biggest reason we're moving to civihosting !), but do have access to the MySQL database.

For the WordPress migration, we have been using the export/import tool in WordPress successfully, so that doesn't seem to be a problem.

Can I simply export the CiviCRM database from the current hosting provider and import it into civihosting? I understand I should drop the current database at civihosting first? As far as I know, I won't be losing anything important (I haven't done much yet in CiviCRM at civihosting).

Also, does anyone know of step-by-step instructions somewhere for doing this?

I'm comfortable with phpMyAdmin, if that comes into the picture.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Steps that i usually follow to migrate CiviCRM from one server to another

1. Export DB from current site.
2. Compress files structure of civicrm i.e /wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm or /wp-content/uploads/civicrm
3. Drop and create the database on CiviHosting.
4. Import db from #1.
5. Replace /wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm or /wp-content/uploads/civicrm from #2.
6. Re-Check civicrm.settings.php.
7. Log out from wordpress and log in.
8. Rebuild Menu and Trigger

   http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1&triggerRebuild=1
9. Check and Update path in Administer >> System Settings >> Directories.
10. Check and Update path in Administer >> System Settings >> Resource URL.
11. Check and Update path in Administer >> System Settings >> Cleanup and Cache

Answer (score 0):

Usually I export from PHPMyAdmin on the old site and then import the same way at the new site. I've always moved all my files and exported/imported the database myself so that everything was exactly the same. I'm not sure of what issues you might right into when just doing the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you:

1. Delete and then recreate the civicrm database at your account with [CiviHosting](https://civihosting.com/)
2. Export your other DB via phpMyAdmin, and select the custom settings and use compression like .zip or .tar.gz
3. Launch phpMyAdmin on CiviHosting and import

If both sites are using WordPress, then all you need to do is log in to WordPress on the CiviHosting site and confirm that the URL and Resource Directory settings are still correct.

Beyond that, it should work fine. If not, you can contact CiviHosting directly and I'm sure they would assist you.